# is this logic of group by in oracle database right?

Tags: oracle

first,i executed this sql in oracle database:

```
select data,count(*) from table_a
```

the database returned a error:ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.
that's ok,but then,i modified the sql like this:

```
select sum from (select data,count(*) as sum from table_a)
```

the database executed successfully,i dont think this is a correct way.
any people know if it is correct?

additional:
guys ,i just want to show the problem of oracle database,i knew what is right ,but i am confused about the result of the second sql.

Comment: Are you sure this second query is the complete query? Oracle would at least demand a from clause at the end.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Only before Oracle 23, which removes the restriction of a `FROM` clause (but would then assume the `DUAL` table is being used). But it still should be invalid as the inner query does not have a `GROUP BY` clause and the outer aggregation cannot sum two columns.

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. `sum(tuple)` is logically invalid, because you have (at least in mathematical abstraction, and then in it's implementation inside a database) to define addition on those tuples. Not any random *data* may be additive

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sorry,i checked and edited the content again

Comment: @MT0 actually,the second sql statement can be executed successfully in oracle database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the count for each unique `data` then:

```sql
select data,
       count(*)
from   table_a
GROUP BY data;
```

Or if you want to count all the rows:

```sql
select count(*)
from   table_a
```

If you want to get all rows and a count then use an analytic function instead of an aggregation function:

```sql
select data,
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY data) AS count_per_data,
       count(*) OVER () AS total_count
from   table_a
```

Your second query is syntactically invalid as the inner query does not have a GROUP BY clause.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wYwCT77F)

Comment: actually,the second sql statement can be executed successfully in oracle database

Comment: @ANTHONY added a Fiddle which shows that it is invalid in Oracle 21. If you want to claim that it is valid then please add a [MRE] which demonstrates under which version, table structure, etc. it is valid.

Comment: i did same test on different oracle database versions,the result is ,on oracle 11gr2,the second sql can  be executed successfully，but failed on a lastest version,it looks like the performance depends on versions.

Comment: @ANTHONY It looks more like a bug in early versions of Oracle. Your query is actually behaving as if it was rewriting the query to push the aggregation function to the outer-query and is ignoring the `data` column in the sub-query so it is as if it was written as `select count(*) from table_a`. I've tried various techniques to materialise the inner query but they all get ignored [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yl-ZDLpx).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to make your first query correct/valid are:

```sql
SELECT data, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM table_a
GROUP BY data;
```

This aggregates the counts by each `data` group.  If you really want `COUNT(*)` by itself in the select clause, then use the following:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM table_a;
```

Here we are simply taking the count of all records across the entire table.  It would not make any sense to also select `data` here, because it isn't clear *which* `data` value you want to display along with the entire table level count.